# The 'msxsl' command line tool does not print xsl:message to the standard output.

Tags: xslt, msxsl

I am currently using the 'msxsl' commandline tool to process my xml. I have some 
 xsl:message in the xslt I use to debug, but these messages are not printed to the console.

Is there any setting or command line argument for 'msxsl' to print the xsl:message? OR is it redirected somewhere else other than standard output/error?

Is there any other commandline tool I can use on Windows?

Comment: If your target XSLT processor is Microsoft's MSXML then using that tool seems the right option, I am sorry, I don't know about the `xsl:message` problem. As for other command line tools, the XSLT world has moved since 1999 and XSLT 1.0 (which MSXML supports) to XSLT 2.0 in 2007 and to XSLT 3.0 in 2017. And with the .NET version of Saxon 9.8 HE https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.8/ there is an open-source XSLT 3 processor available that has a command line interface http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/commandline/ and runs on Windows, like any .NET program.

Comment: Thank You, The Transform.exe tool works perfectly!
" Transform.exe -s:input.xml -xsl:sample.xslt -o:output.xml "